# java, inheritance — private field in parent is accessed through a public method in child

Tags: java, inheritance, private, public

So, one friend sent me this code and said that it had compiled successfully and returned 42.
But, the bothering thing is the method in parent class that "returns" 42 is private, and the method that is called on is in child class, and it's public. So, can anybody tell why and how this works?

```
static class A {
    private int f() {
        return 42;
    }
}

static class B extends A {
    public int f2() {
        return super.f();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(new B().f2());

}
```

It returns 42.

I tried to get rid of static, and

```
class A {
    private int f() {
        return 42;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public int f2() {
        return super.f();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m= new Main();
    B b= m.new B();
    System.out.print(b.f2());

}
```

it still returns 42.

Answer (score 6):

Since both of the classes (`A` and `B`) are nested in `Main`, they can access the `private int f()` method.

If you extract the sources of `A` and `B` in top-level classes, this won't happen and you'll fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The point of private is that "outside" classes should not be able to see private variables. But A and B are both part of the same class, or are nested within each other, so they can access each others private members.

So this will work:

```
public class A {

   private void a() {
     int bVal = this.new B().val;   //! Accessing B private
   }

   class B {
      A a = new A();
      private int val = 10;
      public void b() {
         a.a();      // !! Accessing A private
      }
}
```

BUT, this will fail, even if both A and B are in the same **file** but not within each other:

```
class A {
    private void a() {}
}

class B extends A {
   A a = new A();
   public void b() {
      a.a();  // can't see even if B extends A
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because both classes A and B are nested inside another class, i.e both classes are inner classes of (or "part of") another same class. Since they (Data Members and Methods) are basically a member of the outer class,they are accessible within other inner classes even if private.

Java allows us Nesting of classes,If You Don't know about nested classes first read this :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

```
class Outer{


class A {
    private int f() {
        return 42;
    }//Method f() is a private member of A and accessible by Outer
}

class B extends A {
    public int f2() {
        return super.f(); 
    }//As class B is inner class of Outer it can access members of outer,thus indirectly member of A 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(new B().f2());

}

}
```